# Getting the document from the window in javascript while also checking the document has been loaded

Tags: javascript, window, document

I was trying to execute the following javascript and found that the alert box does not display anything. Is it the case that the document has not loaded and hence no value has been populated ? Below is the code for your reference.

```
function openWindow() {
    window1=window.open('https://www.yahoo.com/');
    var document1=window1.document;
    alert(document1.title);
}
```

Comment: you need to call function openWindow()

Answer (score 0):

For executing function in javascript, you need to call the function.

```
function openWindow() {
    window1=window.open('https://www.yahoo.com/');
    var document1=window1.document;
    alert(document1.title);
}
openWindow()
```

Comment: I already placed the openWindow() call in the HTML code. Still could not understand why this did not work ? If it is due to the document not loading before the alert can be executed then is there any work around ?